# can not GET from passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport-facebook

When I am learning the passport middleware, I'm trying to integrate it with the new Express 4 Router() function.

But when trying passport-facebook middleware, with code:

```
router.route('/auth/facebook')
    .get(passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope : 'email'}));

router.route('auth/facebook/callback')
    .get( passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/'
    }));
```

I encountered the following problem:

```
Error: read ETIMEDOUT
at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/Users/home/WorkSpaces/MEAN/EasyAuth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:348:17)
at /Users/home/WorkSpaces/MEAN/EasyAuth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:171:43
at exports.OAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken (/Users/home/WorkSpaces/MEAN/EasyAuth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18)
at ClientRequest.exports.OAuth2._executeRequest (/Users/home/WorkSpaces/MEAN/EasyAuth/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:148:5)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1551:9)
at CleartextStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1455:17)
at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Socket._destroy.self._writableState.errorEmitted (net.js:440:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the excellent tutorial at

- http://scotch.io/series/easy-node-authentication

The `ETIMEDOUT` could be an invalid `redirect_uri`, but it's difficult to tell from the error message.

Comment: thanks, yes I'm looking into this tut, but it's still using the express 3 style app.get function; I'm trying to migrate it into express 4 style router.rout style code. But seems like it's not working well

Comment: There's a part where they show the Migration to Express 4. Last page.